# unable to set validity on form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to set a validation token "fooname" for a form through its controller, on the click of a button based on a condition.

However it looks like form.$error.fooname is not getting set. {{form.$error.fooname}} is parsed as null.

javascript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data={};
    $scope.data.validate=function () {
        if ($scope.data.name=="foo") {
            $scope.form.$setValidity("fooname",true);
        }
    };
}]);
```

html:

```
<form name="form" ng-controller="controller" 
ng-submit="data.validate()" ng-init="form.$setValidity('fooname',false)" 
novalidate>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.name" name="name"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button><br/>
    {{data}}<br/>
    {{form.$error.fooname}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

The `$setValidity` function defined on form controller, takes three parameter as per the source code:

`form.$setValidity = function(validationToken, isValid, control) {`

Also to fail a validation you need to set the value to `false` not `true`. Change your expression to

`$scope.form.$setValidity("fooname",true,$scope.form);`

Also the `$error` for `FormController` returns the list of controllers that are failing the validation, so you need to adjust you code accordingly.